# Check if every href in a list contains question mark (?) and add ampersand (&) - jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, html-lists, href

I have a list with `href`s. I would like to check if there is a question mark `?` included in this `href`.
If not, add a variable with a question mark `?` at the end of this `href`.
If it includes a question mark add a variable with ampersand `&` at the end of this `href`.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.testone.com/">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testtwo.com/?variable1=ok1">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testthree.com/?variable2=ok2&variable3=ok3">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testfour.com/">link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In above links I would like to add a variable at the end of every `href` so they will become like this:

```
https://www.testone.com/?addedVariable=add 
https://www.testtwo.com/?variable1=ok1&addedVariable=add 
https://www.testthree.com/?variable2=ok2&variable3=ok3&addedVariable=add 
https://www.testfour.com/?addedVariable=add
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find "href" of all links, Than find that it contains "?" or not.

- If there is "?" in link than append "&addedVariable=add".
- Else, append "?addedVariable=add"

```js
$("ul li").find("a").each(function(){
 var link = $(this).attr("href");
  if (link.indexOf("?") !=-1) {
   link += "&addedVariable=add ";
 } else {
   link += "?addedVariable=add ";
  }
  $("#newLinks").append(link + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.testone.com/">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testtwo.com/?variable1=ok1">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testthree.com/?variable2=ok2&variable3=ok3">link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.testfour.com/">link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="newLinks"></div>
```